# How to retrieve value of MyModule.psd1 hash values such as RootModule, ModuleVersion, and HelpInfoURI from within MyModule.psm1?

Tags: powershell, module, manifest

I Need Some Introspection because there are many versions of the same module name floating around in different directories and PSRepositories and the running PS script needs to know which version is currently running.

Given a boilerplate powershell `.\MyModule\MyModule.psd1` manifest and `.\MyModule\MyModule.psm1` module, how does one reference the values in `MyModule.psd1` from within `MyModule.psm1`?

```
# MyModule.psd1: 

@{
# Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest.
RootModule = 'MyModule.psm1'

# Version number of this module.
ModuleVersion = '2020.1.12.1611'

# Author of this module
Author = 'MeMyselfI'
}
```

And the module MyModule.psm1:

```
#MyModule.psm1   

write-host "$RootModule VERSION: $ModuleVersion by $Author"
write-host "For help, please see $HelpInfoURI"
write-host "$PrivateData[PSData].Tags"
```

How does one get the value of `MyModule.psd1` hash entry constants such as `RootModule`, `ModuleVersion`, `HelpInfoURI`, `Path`, and even `$PrivateData[$PSData].Tags` from within the corresponding `MyModule.psm1`?  Introspection in PowerShell must be easy, but my module does not know what it is, help it find itself:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use `Get-Module` along with the name of your module and from there, you have access to all those values.

```
$ModuleInfos = Get-Module -Name MyModule

write-host "$($ModuleInfos.RootModule) VERSION: $($ModuleInfos.Version) by $($ModuleInfos.Author)"
write-host "For help, please see $($ModuleInfos.HelpInfoUri)"
write-host $ModuleInfos.PrivateData.PSData.Item('Tags')
```

You can also do it from any Powershell console window from anywhere provided your module is already imported (From within the psm1, you do not need to import the module though).

Here is an alternative method to achieve the same thing (from within the psm1 file)

```
$ModuleInfos = Import-PowerShellDataFile -Path "$PsScriptRoot\MyModule.psd1"
```

Comment: i have many versions of the same module name floating around.  i have zero confidence that Get-Module MyModule will return the correct version of MyModule,  the one I am currently using.  There must be a built in dot operator or ***this*** reference to make sure I am getting the current module version.

Comment: @rjt  `$ModuleInfos = Import-PowerShellDataFile -Path "$PsScriptRoot\MyModule.psd1"`  Add that in your psm1 and you'll have access to the psd1 in the same folder than the module to display Version and other informations available to you.

Comment: $PSScriptRoot and Import-PowerShelldataFile works much better.